# What unit scope do I need for this?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to install a 3rd party package and I get a compile error:

```
[DCC Error] fiile/line : E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Windows'
```

which refers to this line:

```
wnd := Windows.GetFocus;
```

It seems fairly obvious that I don't have my Unit Scopes right - but which do I need (and is there a general approach to find which use clause I need)?

I currently have

```
Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;
Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell;Winapi;System.Win
```

[Update]

```
interface
uses
SysUtils, winapi.windows, Classes, Controls, ExtCtrls, Graphics, StdCtrls, 
Dialogs, IniFiles, winapi.messages, Forms, Math
{$IFDEF DELPHI6_LVL}
, Variants
{$ENDIF}
;
```

No uses in the impementation section.

[Upate]
I forgot to mention. I failed (in the same way) to install it on one laptop. Then I succeeded on a second. The trouble is that I'd rather have it on my desktop and after a fresh install of XE2 starter I get these problems.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this is not an error that would normally occur in 3rd party packages tested for older versions of Delphi. You would however see it in your own code if you copy and paste to an event handler of a new form in Delphi XE2.

Comment: +1 Thanks, alas it does :-(   A fresh install of XE2 starter & I can't manually install a very widely installed package (on soem PCs; it worke don one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your uses names the Windows unit at all, it would appear to do so by naming the unit as Winapi.Windows. And so your code must also do so and be written as

```
wnd := Winapi.Windows.GetFocus;
```

When you use a unit by naming the fully scoped unit name, you must also use the fully scoped name in subsequent code in that unit.

Now, if you want to use the name Windows then you must name the unit as Windows in the uses clause and let the unit alias setting do its job. If you imported the unit by naming it Windows then your original code will work.

To be very clear:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows;
```

is what you have now but you would need:

```
uses
  Windows;
```

for your code to compile.

Comment: +1 but please see my comment to Rudy. It worked without on one PC and the authors say it should work without on all. So what's wrong with my desktop?

Comment: The explanation for the error you see is what RRUZ, Henrick and I say. If you need more help, I suggest you show the uses clause of the unit that results in the compile error.

Comment: Your update to the question confirms what we have been saying. The code `uses` `winapi.windows` and so must also use that name in scope resolution.

Comment: +1 but ... since I have winapi in the unit scope list surely that ought not to be a problem?

Comment: @Mawg This is how Embarcadero implemented the feature. If you name the unit `Winapi.Windows` in your uses clause, then you have to name it `Winapi.Windows` in the rest of the unit. I think your question has been answered.

Comment: +1 ok, I will award you the answer and take it up with the package authors (BUT, I still don't udnertsand why it did install without modification on one laptop)

Answer (score 3):

You unit scope looks fine, so try these two options

declare in your *uses* section **Windows** instead of **Winapi.Windows**

or modify your code like so

```
wnd :=  Winapi.Windows.GetFocus;
```

Comment: It's the other way around. If the uses section entry is Winapi.Windows, the qualified identifier has to be Winapi.Windows.GetFocus as well. If the uses section entry is Windows, the existing code is fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just correct the first workaround, originally I wrote `Winapi.Windows instead of Windows` but I meant `Windows instead of Windows.WinApi`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, there are times when my poor knowledge of English plays tricks on me.

Comment: +1 all around.  Rudy, I am using a very well known component suite.  I only have XE2 starter, so have no choice but to install manually. It worked fine on my laptop; then I realized I would rather have it on my desktop. With a fresh XE2 install, I get errors.   If I have to edit the code it would mean literally hundreds of errors & when I suggested that the authors were shocked & insisted that I just need to set the use clauses, but I did and I still get the errors ....

Comment: @Mawg: Rudy? Did you mean me? I am not Rodrigo, and I am not from Chile.